# Magento 2 external PHP script with block output always has template hints

Tags: magento2

I am creating a playground **external PHP script** in **Magento 2**, trying to output a static block. It works but the block output always has template path hints -- how can I get rid of the red? Template hints are disabled everywhere in config and Mage mode is set to "developer".

### Block class

/app/code/Ont/Ax/Block/Aif/Agreements.php

```
<?php
namespace Ont\Ax\Block\Aif;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Agreements extends Template {
    function __construct(Template\Context $context) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function foo() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

### Block template

/app/code/Ont/Ax/view/frontend/templates/aif/agreements.phtml

```
<h1>Agreements</h1>
<h2>Foo? <?php echo $this->foo() ?></h2>
```

### Test file

/__local.test.brief.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
/* @var Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager */
$storeManager = $obj->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
$storeManager->setCurrentStore(1);
/* @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout */
$layout = $obj->create("\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface");
$block = $layout->createBlock("Ont\Ax\Block\Aif\Agreements");
$block->setTemplate("aif/agreements.phtml");
echo $block->toHtml();
```

### Result

[image: Screenshot of result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the below lines of code after `$state->setAreaCode('frontend');`

```
$configLoader = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface');
$obj->configure($configLoader->load('frontend'));
```

This worked for me. Reference: [Magento2 - Command-Line - Sending Email Using Block Templates - Error: Missing required argument $debugHintsPath](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152089/magento2-command-line-sending-email-using-block-templates-error-missing-r)